# Setup Hot Restart fails

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui, hot-reload, .net-maui

[image]

"There was an error while trying to automatically provision the project, please check the logs."

The log entry from Visual Studio when opening "Setup Hot Restart" is

```
<entry>
    <record>539</record>
    <time>2022/05/24 00:39:43.654</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>window manager</source>
    <description>Stored pinned views in SUO: </description>
 </entry>
```

When the actual error occurs, there is no further log entry written.

**These are the steps involved to get to this error.**

- Followed the instructions according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?pivots=devices-ios
- According to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJUcBQ07jSc and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTQxCndn5dg I don't need a Mac to test on local iOS device, when using "Hot Restart"
- For the "Debug Target" I choose "iOS Local Devices" and then the IPhone that is plugged into my computer
- "Setup Hot Restart Wizard" appears
- I enter my credentials for the Apple Developer Account (Paid)
- I choose the Team, which is me
- The error appears

**Environment**

- Windows 10 Home - 21H2
- Visual Studio 17.3.0 Preview 1.0
- Windows UI Library (WinUI) 3
- IPhone 13 Pro Max, iOS 15.3.1
- ITunes 12.9.3.3

Comment: Might be wrong, Thinking here is there an incompatibility between MS and Apple right now.  Auto provision has also stopped working in Xamarin development over the last couple weeks for us too

Comment: So then, how do you actually test an app on the IPhone? Publish it in the App Store?

Comment: No, at the moment we’re stuck releasing an update.  Seems iOS provisioning is kind of broken.  Our Current theory might be something in our Git repo is preventing signing certificates/ profiles being written correctly

Comment: Been having the same exact problem for two or three weeks as well.  Still haven't found a fix.

Comment: I got past this by resyncing via itunes on windows

Comment: @Paddymac What do you mean by "resyncing via itunes on windows". How would that procedure look like?

Comment: @Chris I just opened itunes on windows, with the iphone connected - it automatically started resyncing and then when I opened VS the issue with the hot restart loading had stopped

Comment: @Chris also try setting your provisioning profile to manual under the ios project settings; Ive had to do that a few times

Comment: @Paddymac Thank you for the comments. Unfortunately none of this works for me. I am also having this issue lately: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8202, it is said that with Preview 3 it's going to be fixed.

Comment: @Chris I've also noticed myself that hot restart only works with me on visual studio 2022, no idea why it wouldn't work on 2019 - but definitely worth a try